# What is the best way to add JSLink inside form tag

Tags: javascript, custom-list, jslink, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to add JSLink insided for tag in my SharePoint Hosted App, Here is Form tag code

```
  <Form Type="NewForm" 
        Name="{878B105CA-A7O8-7C28-HD7F-5B0DCBA7DSA}"
        SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" 
        WebPartZoneID="Main" 
        Url="NewForm.aspx" 
        Default="TRUE" 
        FormID="0">
```

But the tag inside JSLink is not working. How to achieve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my understanding you can add jslink like

```
<Form Type="NewForm" 
        Name="{878B105CA-A7O8-7C28-HD7F-5B0DCBA7DSA}"
        SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" 
        WebPartZoneID="Main" 
        Url="NewForm.aspx" 
        Default="TRUE" 
        FormID="0" 
        JSLink="~site/Scripts/myJS.js ">
```

You can also add more than one JSLink using **|**

```
 <Form Type="NewForm" 
        Name="{878B105CA-A7O8-7C28-HD7F-5B0DCBA7DSA}" 
        SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" 
        WebPartZoneID="Main" Url="NewForm.aspx" 
        Default="TRUE" 
        FormID="0" 
        JSLink="~site/Scripts/JS.js | ~site/Scripts/yourJS.js"">
```